# Characteristic polynomials for matrix A, involving the Identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let us say we have a square matrix A, where A's characteristic polynomial is defined as
$P_A(t) = \det (t I - A)$
(In this problem, I represents the identity matrix which has the same dimensions as  A. Note that when this determinant is expanded, a polynomial in $t$ is obtained.)

(a) What is the characteristic polynomial of the matrix
$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}?$
Express your answer in form $p_2 t^2 + p_1 t + p_0$.

(b) For the polynomial you found in part a), find the value of
$p_2 A^2 + p_1 A + p_0 I.$

I think I may know how to do part a): I will find the value of $tI-A$, find the determinant of the resulting matrix, and rearrange it so it is in form $p_2 t^2 + p_1 t + p_0$.

However, I have no idea how I am going to solve part b). Help is appreciated.

Thanks.
--Grace

Comment: Just plug in the matrix $A$ to the polynomial that you get. You expect 0.

Comment: I think you are intended to *calculate*. For a preview of what you are expected to get after the calculation, please look up the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, say on Wikipedia.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I looked up the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. Does that mean, somehow for part b), it will yield the value $0$?

Comment: Yes, you will get the zero $2\times 2$ matrix. Just calculate $A^2$ and plug in to the characteristic polynomial that you got,

Comment: @AndréNicolas Great thanks. I will update if I was able to reach the answer.

Comment: Things should go well. The characteristic polynomial is $t^2-(a+d)t+ad-bc$. Calculate $A^2-(a+d)A +(ad-bc)I$. For example the upper left-hand entry of $A^2$  is $(a^2+bc)$. We subtract $(a+d)a$ and add $ad-bc$. We get $0$. Three more to go!